# Eliminar un valor en concreto de un localstorage

Tags: javascript

soy estudiante de javascript y realice una to do list, el problema es que cuando elimino una tarea de la lista, se elimina solo del html y no del localstorage, por ende cuando aprieto f5 se vuelve a poner.

Ademas me gustaria saber como podria evitar que se puedan poner tareas en blanco, ya que intento con un if pero no me lo toma, ya probe de muchas formas y la verdad no puedo solucionarlo, desde ya muchisimas gracias.

a continuacion les dejo el codigo como lo tengo escrito, ademas si tienen alguna recomendacion para mejorar me serviria demasiado

```
let tareasNuevas

let contador = 0

// Obtenemos el id de la lista
let lista = document.getElementById("lista")

// Ver si hay tareas antiguas o si el array está vacío
let tareasViejas = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("tareas")) || []

console.log(tareasViejas)
// Si el array viejo tiene items al momento de cargar la página entonces mostramos las tareas

let agregar_tareasViejas = (tareasViejas.length > 0) ?  mostrarTareas() : null



// Boton para agregar las tareas
let boton = document.getElementById("boton")
boton.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    agregarTareas()
})

function agregarTareas() {
    // Obtener la tarea nueva
    tareasNuevas = document.getElementById("tareas")
    
    // Guardar la tarea nueva en el array
    tareasViejas.push(tareasNuevas.value)
    console.log(tareasViejas)

    tareasNuevas.value = ""

    // Guardar el nuevo array en el localStorage

    mostrarTareas()
}

function mostrarTareas() {
    // Vaciamos el placeholder
    contador++;
    lista.innerHTML = ""
    // Mostramos nueva lista por cada tarea, usamos reverse para mostrar la ultima tarea primero
    tareasViejas.reverse().forEach((tarea) => {
        lista.innerHTML += `
        <div class="contenedor-tareas" id="${contador}">
        <input type="checkbox" name="" class="form-check-input mt-0" id="checkbox">
        <label for="">${tarea}</label>
        <img src="imagenes/borrar.png" alt="" class="borrar" id="Borrar">
        </div>
    `
    })
        localStorage.setItem("tareas", JSON.stringify(tareasViejas))
}

// Tareas Pendientes y Completadas
let actualizacion = () =>{
    // Llamaremos a todos los div que seran las Tareas a realizar en la lista
    let element = lista.querySelectorAll(`div`);
    // Llamaremos todos los Checkbox checkeados en la lista
    let checkbox = lista.querySelectorAll(`input[type="checkbox"]:checked`);
    // Pinteremos en el div llamado Stats, las tareas pendientes y tareas a realizar
    stats.innerHTML = `<p>Tareas Totales: ${element.length} Completadas: ${checkbox.length}</p>`;

}

// Agregamos un evento a la lista para saber donde hacemos click
lista.addEventListener("click", (e) =>{
    //Si hacemos un click en cualquier INPUT de la lista se actualizaran los Stats
    if (e.srcElement.nodeName == "INPUT") {
        actualizacion();
    } 
    // si hacemos click en cualquier IMG de la lista se ejecutara la funcion borrar tarea con los parametros id
    else if (e.srcElement.nodeName == "IMG"){
        console.log(e.srcElement.parentNode.id);
        borrarTarea(e.srcElement.parentNode.id)
    }   
    });

    let borrarTarea = (id) =>{
        let tareaABorrar =  document.getElementById(id);
        lista.removeChild(tareaABorrar);
        
        actualizacion();
        }
```

Comment: intenta utilizando este método: `storage.removeItem(keyName);`